# using the word "subject" for a state in English

Tags: word-usage

Is it common to refer to a state as a "subject" in English and to a part of that state as "object"? It is common in my first language, but I haven't seen that happening in English.

EDIT:
By "state" I mean a political entity. In my first language (Russian) it is very common to refer to a sovereign political state - that is, a state that can act on its own and can decide its own future - as a "subject", while an entity that cannot do that on its own and whose future is pretty much defined by some other government above it besides its own government is referred to as an "object". I thought that the same usage was existing in English, but when I looked it up in English Wikipedia I couldn't find an article on it.

Comment: Wikipedia has an article on "federal subjects of Russia". Is that what you have in mind? Most English speakers would be entirely unfamiliar with this terminology. Wikipedia probably uses it because it presumably corresponds to the Russian terminology, and it may make sense to people who are closely familiar with the Russian system.

Comment: Could you please add some context to your question? We need to be clear on what you mean by "state" - a political state? A condition? Can you give an example from your own language and indicate your research, for example what translation dictionaries tell you is the equivalent English word?

Comment: @Astralbee By "state" I mean a political entity. In my first language (Russian) it is very common to refer to a sovereign political state - that is, a state that can act on its own and can decide its own future - as a "subject", while an entity that cannot do that on its own and whose future is pretty much defined by some other government above it besides its own government is referred to as an "object". I thought that the same usage was existing in English, but when I looked it up in English Wikipedia I couldn't find an article on it.

Comment: The question remains obscure. Anything that can do or be anything can be a "subject". Russia is a soverign political state. Moscow is "under" Russia, right? I have just used each as the subject of the previous two sentences. A person who lives in Moscow is "under" both Russia and Moscow, but I have also just used it as a subject. Any noun can be used as a subject. As it's currently written, I'm voting to close teh question. Please try to explain further.

Comment: @JimReynolds - Is Moscow a state? Is person living in Moscow a state?

Comment: @bri Moscow can be a state, when used to symbolize “Russia”, just as “The Crown” can mean “The UK”. Moscow qua the city is also a “political entity” so is every person. Please define “state” more clearly than “a political entity”. It’s a complex term. Can you just as easily use country or nation to ask the question? Clearly, some progress is being made toward clarifying the question. Can you try to re-write the question to reflect that if you wish to keep it open?

Comment: Saying, in English, that “x=y” in Russian is problematic. There are multiple possible points of reference and readers likely cannot understand what you intend.

Comment: Ambiguous language: “John can refer to a person” vs “John can mean ‘person’. Neither “subject” nor “object” are used to denote “state” in English. Might that answer your question? Can you provide a concrete example and ask if it’s felicitous or meaningful? E.g., “Israel is, in name a sovereign country, but in reality it is an object of the US. It dare not take any significant action without the US’s permission”. We do not use object in that way.

Comment: @JimReynolds "Moscow can be a state, when used to symbolize “Russia”" - I am asking you about Moscow in your earlier example: "Russia is a sovereign political state. Moscow is "under" Russia, right?" Clearly, Moscow in that example does not  symbolize "Russia", but is some part of it. "Moscow qua the city is also a “political entity” so is every person" - Perhaps, a person may be in some very specific cases a political entity (I'd have to rack my brain here), but can a person be a state? After all, my question was: "Is person living in Moscow a state?"

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not used in English.

A "Subject" in the political sense is a person who is subservient to another. It is contrasted with "Citizen" who has an equal right to other people.

> The King waved at his subjects from the window of his palace.

and "Object" is not used in a political sense.

In the context of the Russian federation, there are various constituents.  Some have a greater degree of independence and are termed "субъект" (literally "subject")  This term is used by some who study Russian politics to mean "one of the more independent constituents of the Russian Federation".  However, just like the "States" in the USA, they don't have full sovereignty.  You should not use this term except in the context of the Russian Federation.

There is a particular term "Subject of the Russian Federation", meaning a member of the federation that is, therefore, *not* an independent and sovereign state.  (Some subjects of the federation are titled "Oblasts" and some "Republics") That term is not used outside of Russian political discourse.

In English, there are a range of terms, and they differ by location more than by dialect.  The keyword is the adjective "sovereign". If an entity has sovereignty it is free to do as it pleases without reference to a higher government.

So Canada and France have sovereignty.  But Texas and Scotland don't.

You might investigate the terms "country", "nation", "state" as they have overlapping meanings, and none is used exclusively for sovereign regions.

Comment: "There is a particular term "Subject of the Russian Federation", meaning a member of the federation that is, therefore, not an independent and sovereign state" - I think the meaning here is direct opposite: unlike parts of a large unitary state, they are members of a federation and, therefore, are more independent than regions of a unitary state, hence, they are referred to as "subjects" in Russian (as opposed to "objects" that have no freedom at all).

Comment: They are not independent nor sovereign.  They might have more independence than the various "oblasts"  (not objects, that word is not used at all) but the term is only used by Russia polictical analysts, and has no currency.  You could not say "Wales is a oblast, but England is a subject.  The terms don't apply to the UK  (Wales is a principality, and England is a country, but neither are independent nor sovereign.)

Comment: I didn't say they are "independent". I said they are "more independent". They are simply members of a federation, that is, they have more freedom from Moscow then, say, any region of a unitary state of Ukraine from Kiev. And this is exactly what the Russian word for "subject" ("субъект") implies. The word for "object" ("объект"), on the other hand,  implies having no freedom at all. Thus, any region of Ukraine would be referred to in Russian as "object". Obviously, this usage is not in English.

Comment: Indeed,  not English.  I think my answer stands.  The word "subject" means a person in a kingdom or similar

Comment: Your answer stands, of course, except you've attached the wrong meaning to "subject" in "Subject of Russian Federation". That term comes from Russian and the original connotation in there in Russian is "more independent than object" rather than what is implied by the English word "subject" in English. The problem here is that the term was translated from Russian with word-for-word correspondence, hence, the misunderstanding. It's a common case with translating terms or titles. Like, for example, "War and Peace", "Master and Margaret", etc. -- all are translated wrong into English.

Comment: Okay, I've edited.  I still can't find any use of "Object" to refer to a less independent part of the russian federation.  I can find "Oblast" which may be related.

Answer (score 0):

I think the words you are looking for are “sovereign” and “subordinate.” Thus, in the political description of the U.S., the constituent states are sovereign with respect to certain issues, e.g., the law of divorce, whereas the federal government is sovereign with respect to the most important issues, e.g., policy with respect to foreign states and with commerce between two of the constituent states. A U.S. state may not contravene a law of the U.S. on any topic where the U.S. is sovereign.